# Error using cte on HIVE SQL - java.lang

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, common-table-expression, pyspark

As per https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression  i see that CTEs are supported in HIVE. However, i get the below error when trying to execute a simple CTE

```
 An error occurred while calling o60.sql.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.set(ThreadLocal.java:201)
```

I get this error when trying the below query to fetch all parents of a destination node

```
  nodelist = sqlContext.sql("""
       SELECT node,src from known
""")
nodelist.registerTempTable("nodelist") 

pathcalc = sqlContext.sql("""  
        WITH    nodeMaster
      AS ( SELECT   p.node,
                    p.src
           FROM     nodelist p
           WHERE    p.node = """+dest+"""
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   c.node,
                    c.src
           FROM     nodeMaster cte
                    INNER JOIN nodelist c ON c.node = cte.src
         )
        SELECT  node
        FROM    nodeMaster m
""")
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Hive reference for Spark. Not all Hive features are supported in Spark. For more information see [Supported Hive Features](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features) in [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

You reference your CTE table nodeMaster inside it's WITH clause. According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression, this recursive reference is not supported.

Instead you may want to do something like

```
    WITH nodedest AS 
      ( SELECT p.node,
               p.src
           FROM nodelist p
           WHERE p.node = {dest}
      )
    SELECT nodelist.node
    FROM nodedest  
    INNER JOIN nodelist 
      ON nodelist.node = nodedest.src
```